# Detect CSS transform change across browsers using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I need to detect if the CSS transform property has changed using jQuery. In firebug the CSS property i'm looking to detect changes on is rendered like this:

`-moz-transform: translate(-0px, 0px)`

I need to detect whether this has changed to another pixel property. For example:

`-moz-transform: translate(-100px, 0px)`

More details:

Ultimately I'm trying to detect between a click and a drag on the following demo.

http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/carousel/

I figured that I could query `mouseup` on the current transform property and if it remained the same that it was a click or if the transform property changed it would be a drag.

Comment: The user would change it by dragging a container with a large overflow.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a bigger problem. Unless this is literally all you need to do, it would be to your benefit to explain what you're doing and why you need this - your solution may not be the only one, or might be too much work, or just isn't the right one. EDIT: Can't you just use a callback for after the user drags the container?

Comment: added more details about the issue. If there is an easier way to accomplish the ultimate goal, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Modernizr to create the vender prefix and then you can use `.split()` to break apart the output from `.css()` and get the desired values.

Here is a method of getting the properly prefixed property:

```
if (Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {
    trans_key = Modernizr.prefixed('transform').replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(str,m1){ return '-' + m1.toLowerCase(); }).replace(/^ms-/,'-ms-');

} else if (Modernizr.csstransforms) {
    trans_key = Modernizr.prefixed('transform').replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(str,m1){ return '-' + m1.toLowerCase(); }).replace(/^ms-/,'-ms-');
}
```

*Source: http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#prefixed*

Then you can use `.css()` to get the `-vender-transform` property:

```
var matrix = $('#element-id').css(trans_key);//output = matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 100px, 0px)
```

Then finally you can `.split()` the `matrix` value into something useable:

```
var data = matrix.replace(')', '').split(',');//data[4]='100px', data[5]='0px'
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Yz8B/